# Run a shell command from Gnome search box

Tags: gnome-shell

Running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

My question could be syntactically wrong. So, please excuse the wording of the title. Here is a more detailed explanation.

I want to press the Window key and in the search box, key in a shell command, say, mv file1 dir2 and hit enter. So that the command gets executed.

How do I do that? I tried entering that command but nothing happened.

Comment: You don't use that for running commands. Use Alt-F2

Comment: @muru Thanks. But even when I enter `cp file1 dir2` at Alt-F2 prompt, it does not work :(

Comment: The files are in your home directory?

Comment: @muru, Sorry. I had typed the command incorrectly. Will you please post Alt-F2 comment as an answer? I will then accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run commands in GNOME Shell, use the run prompt: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>. From [the cheatsheet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet):

> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> allows entering a command to launch an
>   application. If you want to launch a shell command in a new Terminal
>   window press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> [image]

Comment: The `Ctrl+Enter` key combo _(to open in a new terminal window)_ doesn't seem to work in last Ubuntu versions _(20.04, 20.10)_